# Optional pattern for time in Java 6

Tags: java, datetime, datetime-format

I want to parse time in 24-hour format. The input can be either in the format "H:mm" or of the format "H". In Java 8, there's a nice way to do it:

```
String pTimeIn24Clock="5";
DateTimeFormatter l_oTimeFormat = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("H[:mm]");
LocalTime l_oTime = LocalTime.parse(pTimeIn24Clock, l_oTimeFormat);
```

Is there some elegant way to do such thing using Java 6? I want to avoid calculating the length of the input time string, or placing any code in catch blocks of exceptions.

Comment: Can you use [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormatterBuilder.html#appendOptional-org.joda.time.format.DateTimeParser-)?

Comment: Joda Time is the best...